# Native Script Fetch and Display

Tags: fetch, nativescript

I need the example of the simplest fetch and display using nativescript. If anybody have some github repo, I will appreciate it.
Thanks
Actually, I want to read one JSON and display data in list in native script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vey basic example [in this Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=8eB6LE&v=3) - there are also a lot of examples in the main NativeScript documentation for both [fetch](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/fetch) and [data binding](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding)

Basically, you create the view model using `Observable` and bind it to the XML views (all of the above is related to NativeScript Core - see [this for NativeScript Angula](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-data-binding)r)

```
import { EventData, Observable, fromObject } from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable';
import { StackLayout } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/stack-layout';

// Event handler for Page "pageLoaded" event attached in home-page.xml
export function pageLoaded(args: EventData) {

    let page = <StackLayout>args.object;

    let viewModel = new Observable();
    viewModel.set("items", [])

    fetch("https://httpbin.org/json")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {
            // console.log(res.slideshow.slides[1].items);
            viewModel.set("items", res.slideshow.slides[1].items);
        }).catch((err) => {
    });

    page.bindingContext = viewModel;
}
```

and the ListView to render the list in the XML

```
<ListView class="list-group" items="{{ items }}" itemTap="{{ onItemTap }}" style="height:1250px">
    <ListView.itemTemplate>
        <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" class="list-group-item">
            <Label text="{{ $value }}" />
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Of course, the above is a very simplified example of values received directly as an array of strings. For more options regarding data binding examine [this documentation article](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding)

Answer (score 2):

Would mind sharing a code snippet for a scenario where I want to get data from https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey={API_KEY}. My data are displayed vertically

CBS displayed like:

C

B

S

```js
fetch("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=8f65d5e676e44da89848f43ed0******")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((res) => {
   //console.log(res.slideshow.slides[1].items);
   //viewModel.set("items", res.slideshow.slides[1].items);
   console.log("title: ", res.articles[3].title);
   viewModel.set("title", res.articles[3].title);
  }).catch((err) => {
  });
```

Thank you @Nick Liev